# nuget is not adding references

Tags: .net, nuget

I am having a weird issue to get a reference added to the project's references. Let me first just show the setup I have.

I have two packages: Framework.nuspec and Resources.nuspec. Each containing a dll. The dll in the Framework.nuspec is 88KB and the dll in the Resources.nuspec is 13605 KB.

Framework.nuspec is as follows:

```
<? xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>Framework</id>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
    <title>Framework</title>
    <authors>Author</authors>
    <owners>Owner</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Core functionality</description>
    <copyright>Copyright © 2016 Company</copyright>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Framework.dll" target="lib\net461" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Resources.nuspec is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>Resources</id>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
    <title>Resources</title>
    <authors>Author</authors>
    <owners>Owner</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>All resources</description>
    <copyright>Copyright © 2016 Company</copyright>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Resources.dll" target="lib\net461" />
  </files>
</package>
```

As you can see, the setup for the packages are simple and looks exactly the same, except for the names and files. Then the command to pack these packages is a simple: `nuget.exe pack Framework.nuspec` and `nuget.exe pack Resources.nuspec`

Now what happens is, when I add the Framework package, it adds the reference correctly:
[image: Framework]

But when I add the Resources packages, it doesn't add the reference at all:
[image: Resources]

Is it something I am doing wrong?
Is this a bug that I need to go and report or one that is already reported that I missed?
Has someone encountered this before?
Is it because I'm using net461?

I have created the packages over and over but no success.

Any feed back will be much appreciated.

Kind Regards,
Willem Toerien

UPDATE: Here are the outputs for the adding of the Resources package:

```
Attempting to gather dependencies information for package 'Resources.1.0.2' with respect to project 'ConsoleApplication1', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Resources.1.0.2' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'Resources.1.0.2'
Resolved actions to install package 'Resources.1.0.2'
Adding package 'Resources.1.0.2' to folder 'C:\Users\wtoerien\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\packages'
Added package 'Resources.1.0.2' to folder 'C:\Users\wtoerien\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\packages'
Added package 'Resources.1.0.2' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'Resources 1.0.2' to ConsoleApplication1
========== Finished ==========
```

As you can see, there are no warnings.

Comment: The first thing I'd check: did you have any warnings when you executed `nuget pack` for Resources? And did you check the content of the nupkg?

Comment: Hi Anton, thank you for commenting. In the output there is no warnings. I'll update the question with the output.

Comment: And what about the content of package? Do you have the `dll` in place?

Comment: Yes, I have the dll in place. It's there. I have even tried adding the <references> tag, but to no avail, same result, same output.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, after some playing around, I have found something very odd. As soon as I add "X" to all resources, the `dll` gets added! `Resources.nuspec` to `ResourcesX.nuspec`, `Resources.dll` to `ResourcesX.dll` as well as the title inside the `nuspec` file.

That said, my full notation is `Company.Framework.Plugin.Resources.dll` so essentially when I changed everything to `Company.Framework.Plug.ResourcesX.dll` it worked.

Here is the nuspec:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>Company.Framework.Plugin.ResourcesX</id>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
    <title>Company Web Resources Plugin</title>
    <authors>Company</authors>
    <owners>Company</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Core images and entity name definitions for Framework web applications.</description>
    <copyright>Copyright © 2016 Company, Inc.</copyright>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\*.*" target="lib\net461" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Here is the result:

[image: Resources]

Output is as follows:

```
Attempting to gather dependencies information for package 'Company.Framework.Plugin.ResourcesX.1.0.2' with respect to project 'ConsoleApplication1', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Company.Framework.Plugin.ResourcesX.1.0.2' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'Company.Framework.Plugin.ResourcesX.1.0.2'
Resolved actions to install package 'Company.Framework.Plugin.ResourcesX.1.0.2'
Adding package 'Company.Framework.Plugin.ResourcesX.1.0.2' to folder 'C:\Users\wtoerien\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\packages'
Added package 'Company.Framework.Plugin.ResourcesX.1.0.2' to folder 'C:\Users\wtoerien\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\packages'
Added package 'Company.Framework.Plugin.ResourcesX.1.0.2' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'Company.Framework.Plugin.ResourcesX 1.0.2' to ConsoleApplication1
========== Finished ==========
```

So it seems to me that there is something regarding the `Resources` name that is preventing it from being added. I will log a bug to nuget, but I guess in the meantime we will just have to work around it.

Thanks.

Comment: NuGet treats assemblies that end with .Resources.dll as language resource assemblies and will not reference them. There is a document on creating [localized packages](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-localized-packages). Also see this stackoverflow question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705750/reference-not-added-for-nuget-package/35706842#35706842

Comment: Thank you for your response! I didn't know that.