# Nuget Package Installation is Not Adding References To Project

Tags: c#, nuget

I have published a package in Nuget few years ago. From time to time, I was updating it with new versions and all was ok until now.
Few days ago I've published an update to Nuget and when I've updated my package, it was installed successfully but it never added any references to my project.

I've even started from blank console applications and tried to add my package. Same problem.

You can try. This is a package

https://www.nuget.org/packages/63BITS-Libraries/

This is how I built my package

[image: package metadata screenshot]

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35886540/nuget-is-not-adding-references

Comment: Looks like that this question is not about me. There are no Resources in my nuget package

Comment: The package ends with "Libraries" not "Resources" which should be no issue with localized resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you download your nuget package, and unzip it (yep its just a zip file). You will find that your DLL is not in the lib directory.

Typically, inside a nuget package, any dlls need to be in `lib/<FrameworkVersion>`

For example if your DLL targeted netstandard1.6 then in the nuget package the path to your dll would be `lib/netstandard1.6/SixtyThreeBits.Libraries.dll`

In your package, your dll is in `SixtyThreeBitsLibraries/SixtyThreeBits.Libraries.dll`

Comment: It worked, thank you for finding and error and giving an explanation